# Autowiring HttpSession give different object than HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use Spring Security, and I found strange behavior of framework while login. Spring Security `WebAuthenticationDetails` has parameter `sessionId` which is getting from HTTP request, and it all should be good, but in fact REST request gives me another session id. If I will autowire `HttpSession` and then get session id from it, I will get Spring-like id. So it seems that I have two ids for one user. Is it correct? Or I missed something?

**EDITED:**

For example this class will gave some session id

```
public class AuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

    @Autowired
    HttpSession httpSession;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
            LoggedUser loggedUser = (LoggedUser) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            loggedUser.initSessionParams(event.getAuthentication());
            String sessionId = httpSession.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

and this method will give another one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chart")
public Map getTestStatusesChart(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String sessionId= request.getSession(false).getId();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is next: with condition of security Spring change session id by default. To prevent such behavior you need to disable session-fixation-protection in Spring Security config. more info by [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation)